# If statment ignored inside @Test in Selenium webdrive with Java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, if-statement, testing

1.The Code opens a page then verifies the URL of the page and saves it in a string. enters credentials from an excel file then pushes log in, than checks URL again and saves it in variable url1. If successful log in the url variable is different from url1 variable and driver is reverted to previous page but if credential are wrong and it doesn't log in url1 is equal to url and driver should not revert back, but it dose... if statement is just ignored. Any thoughts?Ps: I have tried try catch block and also using Boolean expressions or checking if element is there but its the same it just runs every line of code ignoring the try catch or if or do statements and if id doesn't find the element it crashes.

2.
    This is the code:

```
public class LogIn{

    public WebDriver driver;

    @Test
      public void main() throws Exception {


        File src= new File("D:\\Eclipse Luna\\ExcelData\\TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(src);

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);    
        XSSFSheet sheet1 = wb.getSheetAt(0);

        int rowcount=sheet1.getLastRowNum();
        String url = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(url);
        for (int i=1;i<rowcount+1;i++){

        String data0=sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        String data1=sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(2).getStringCellValue();


        System.out.println("Username:" + data0);
        System.out.println("Password:" + data1+ "\n");
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(data0);
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(data1);

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(3000);

        String url1 = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(url1);



        if(url != url1){

             driver.navigate().back();
        }

        }

    }

      @BeforeMethod

      public void beforeMethod() {

          // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver

          driver = new FirefoxDriver();

          //Put a Implicit wait, this means that any search for elements on the page could take the time the implicit wait is set for before throwing exception

          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

          //Launch the application.

          driver.get("*****");<- actual link to a website cant provide it tough, sorry.



      }

      @AfterMethod

      public void afterMethod() {

          // Close the driver



      }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`url` and `url1` are strings, you don't compare strings with `!=` or `==` but with `equals`. Try

```
if(!url.equals(url1))
```

The exclamation mark in the beginning means `not`.

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked! :) I am new to java and still learning,again thank you,that helped me a lot.